# Watermark on screen

Tags: windows-7, watermark

My users are not able to see if they are connected to the terminal server or it's the native os.

(Even if native os is win7 with aero; and remoted os is in 16-bit color, windows classic theme... I see that lots of times they are doing the wrong operations)

There is a program that can write a watermark or overlay an image on the screen?

So I could write on the screen "Yeah, you are on the terminal server" or "Oh noes, you are offline"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wallpaper that signifies they are on the terminal server and assign it to the TS users via polices.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using **[bgInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557)**

Formerly from Sysinternals (Mark Russinovitsj fame), now bought by MS and hosted on Technet.

It will allow you to customize the desktop, showing system information of choice, including logged on user, machine name etc. etc.

Comment: I noticed that people can't read. I found it better to assign a wallpaper with HUGE colorful text (>300 points)